# Incremental issue in JS recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, increment

On an [FCC](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-range-of-numbers) exercise I came with this bad code:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum < startNum) {
    return [];
  } else {
    let recurs = rangeOfNumbers(++startNum, endNum)
    recurs.unshift(startNum - 1);
    return recurs;
  }
};
```

Really bad code apart, what called my attention was that **++startNum** worked and **startNum++** was *InternalError: too much recursion*. Looked some other posts and YT videos, but still couldn't  understand it.

Here is the proper code:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum - startNum === 0) {
    return [startNum];
  } else {
    var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    numbers.push(endNum);
    return numbers;
  }
}
```

or even better:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  return startNum === endNum
    ? [startNum]
    : [...rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1), endNum ];
}
```

Comment: even betterer `const range = (a, b) => a > b ? [] : [ a, ...range(a + 1, b) ]`

Comment: startNum++ generates an infinite recursion when ```endNum >= startNum``` because the recursion is called with the same parameters (unchanged), verifies the same condition and calls itself again, and again...